# Not able to use a select query to get number of days in DATEADD function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dateadd

I have a table, Table1, in the following format:

```
Country    No_Of_Days
  XX          5
  YY          10
```

And I need to update  End_Date column in another table, Table2, which has a Start_Date  by adding the days in above mentioned table to Start_date:

```
Country     Start_Date      End_Date    Calc_Manual_Flag
  XX        25-Dec-16       30-Dec-16        CALC
  YY        02-Jan-17       12-Jan-17        CALC
```

I used the following query but it does not seem to work:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table2
SET End_date = 
dateadd(
        day,
        (SELECT No_Of_Days FROM Table1 WHERE Table2.Country = Table1.Country),Start_Date),
    Calc_Manual_Flag = 'CALC'
WHERE Table2.End_Date IS NULL
AND Table2.Start_Date IS NOT NULL
```

But it does not seem to be working properly. The updates do not seem to be happening as expected. I am getting the following error message:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery     follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Kindly provide guidance on this.

Comment: What is it that happens?

Comment: What does not "working properly" mean?  Are you getting errors?  Unexpected values?

Comment: I am getting message 0 rows updated

Comment: sorry worng message...this is the one I am getting

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The message is pretty clear.  The subquery is returning more than one match.  You need to decide what to do and structure the query accordingly.

Comment: A subquery in the select can only return 1 record.  So if your query is returning more values for the given country, use SELECT TOP 1 and an ORDER BY if you need to specify which record to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this query using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET End_date = DATEADD(day, t1.No_Of_Days, t2.Start_Date)
        Calc_Manual_Flag = 'CALC'
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2 JOIN
         Table1 t1
         ON t2.Country = t1.Country
    WHERE t2.End_Date IS NULL AND t2.Start_Date IS NOT NULL;
```

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` if you really want to update rows where there is no match.

This fixes the proximal cause of the problem, which is due to multiple matching rows in `Table11`.  An arbitrary match is used for the update.

To really fix the problem, you need to decide what to do.  If you want to subtract all matching days, then aggregate before joining:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET End_date = DATEADD(day, t1.No_Of_Days, t2.Start_Date)
        Calc_Manual_Flag = 'CALC'
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2 JOIN
         (SELECT Country, SUM(No_Of_Days) as No_Of_Days
          FROM Table1 t1
          GROUP BY Country
         ) t1
         ON t2.Country = t1.Country
    WHERE t2.End_Date IS NULL AND t2.Start_Date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon. Thank you for the answer. Will this work even after the new error message I put up is being shown regarding the subquery?

Comment: Hello Gordon, I tested your solution. It gives me good results. But one odd thing is it doesnt update certain countries randomly eventhough Start_Date is not null and the country is in Table1

Comment: Apologies Gordon. My Table1 was missing a few countries. Hence the no update. But otherwise your query works beautifully. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Error message clearly says that `Country` has duplicates in First table so you need to figure out what you want to do with duplicate rows either `sum` the `no_of_days` or take `no_of_days` based on some order

```
UPDATE t2 
SET    End_date = Dateadd(day, t1.no_of_days, t2.start_date), 
       Calc_Manual_Flag = 'CALC' 
FROM   dbo.table2 t2 
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 no_of_days --sum(no_of_days)
                    FROM   table1 t1 
                    WHERE  t2.country = t1.country 
                    ORDER  BY somecol) cs 
WHERE  t2.end_date IS NULL 
       AND t2.start_date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the help VR46. I went with Gordon's solution.